# Split up files from one big folder to multiple folders in uploads after migration

Tags: uploads, migration

Is it possible to split up images in one uploads folder *after* full migration, and still keep each image attached to the post that it was uploaded to? Ideally I would like to put all images in folders according to the date (month) of the post the image/images belongs to - just like how WordPress behaves normally.

I just migrated a site from Drupal to WordPress, and even though all posts (circa 600 over 8 years) are working fine, all images ended up in one folder (2021>06).

Since there are 176000 images, this folder is too big for most FTP clients to handle (limit for files to be displayed seems to be 9998).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Login via SFTP solved the issue with only 9998 files being visible. But still would prefer to have the folder split up as per my question. If possible...